# One Adobe Acrobat File Across Multiple Monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, adobe-acrobat

How can one open an Adobe Acrobat file across multiple monitors? For example, I use the Scrolling 2-Page feature but at higher magnifications, one screen can't contain both pages, so I'd like to divide the two pages per screen.

I'm cognisant that two instances of the same PDF could be opened, then each instance can be dedicated to one screen, but this feels incommodious.

Info on my Setup: I'm using Windows 7 and the Extend Desktop option thanks to the shortcut Win + P. No programs were used to setup the multiple monitors.

Please feel free to generalise this question to other programs.

Comment: If those monitors are setup in what is called _extended desktop_ mode then certainly. But otherwise the details of how your monitors are configured is pertinent and should be included in your question.

Comment: Thank you. I've added some info to my OP. I'm on extended desktop mode now but can't seem to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd unmaximize the window and drag it across the two monitors.  This assumes you're not mirroring each Screen.

Windows 7 doesn't really manage multiple monitors very well, so that's all you can do if you want to expand across two monitors.. ie manually.